# sorting table by "middle" value of alphabet in mysql

Tags: mysql

so I have a table that has the column "status" where it contains ERROR, FAILED, SUCCESS.
how can I sort it but have FAILED always on the top of the result?
for example, if I sort it by status asc, the result will be :
FAILED
ERROR
SUCCESS

Comment: does the order between 2 same statuses matter? and Is there a possibility of status being something other than the mentioned? if yes then what would be its priority?

Comment: so I expect all data that the status is FAILED always on the top, the order of the same status doesn't matter.
the status will always be between those 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case expression,

```
order by case when status='FAILED' then 0 else 1 end, status
```

Comment: it really just as simple as this how can I not think of it before. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

so you can set the order for each item:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status, "FAILED,SUCCESS,ERROR");
```